# c# Simple score system

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple game. I'm trying to give the player a +1 score when he has a answer correct, but It keeps saying the same score 1. I want to have the score constantly updated when your answer is correct.

So if you have two answers correct, the score should update to 2, but it doesn't and keeps saying 1...

```
        start:

        Random numbergenerator = new Random ();

        int num1 = numbergenerator.Next(1,11);
        int num2 = numbergenerator.Next(1,11);
        int score = 0; // THIS IS THE SCORE

        Console.WriteLine("Whats " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");

        var answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if ( answer == num1 * num2) {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Thats the correct answer!");
            Console.ResetColor();
            ++score; // Gives score
            Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
        } else {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Bummer, try again!");
            Console.ResetColor();
            ++score; // Gives score
            Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
        }
        goto start;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You initialize score to 0 every time through the program.  This is a great opportunity to learn [how to use the debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Also look into `for` and `while` loops instead of using `goto`.

Comment: Besides, if you increment score also when one gives the incorrect answer then...

Comment: Ok thanks BJ Myers

Comment: `goto` should be limited to use by the compiler only. Or at least, that is the guidance given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** From C# specification ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742(v=vs.71).aspx))

> Furthermore, a variable initializer in a local variable declaration corresponds exactly to an assignment statement that is inserted immediately after the declaration.

In other words every time your program goes to `start` assignment statement will init `score` with `0`

i suggest to move the initialization before *start* (it will be better to move numbergenerator *initialization* too. ) :

```
    Random numbergenerator = new Random ();
    int score = 0; // THIS IS THE SCORE

    start:

    int num1 = numbergenerator.Next(1,11);
    int num2 = numbergenerator.Next(1,11);

    Console.WriteLine("Whats " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");

    var answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if ( answer == num1 * num2) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Thats the correct answer!");
        Console.ResetColor();
        ++score; // Gives score
        Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
    } else {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Bummer, try again!");
        Console.ResetColor();
        ++score; // Gives score
        Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
    }
    goto start;
```

**2) Don't use `goto`.** Because

- it makes the code confusing
- reduces readability

this  [article](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html) about GO TO can be interesting for you.

i suggest to replace 
`start` with `while (true){` 
`goto start;` with `}` 
it should looks something like this:

```
    Random numbergenerator = new Random ();
    int score = 0; // THIS IS THE SCORE

    while(true)
    {
        int num1 = numbergenerator.Next(1,11);
        int num2 = numbergenerator.Next(1,11);

        Console.WriteLine("Whats " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");

        var answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if ( answer == num1 * num2) {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Thats the correct answer!");
            Console.ResetColor();
            ++score; // Gives score
            Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
        } else {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Bummer, try again!");
            Console.ResetColor();
            ++score; // Gives score
            Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
        }
    }
```

**3) Extract method**, it is not critical, but i suggest to improve readability by extracting a method. This method will contain loop body. The code should looks something like this:

```
public void TryToGuessMultiplication_GameStep(int num1, int num2)
{
            Console.WriteLine("Whats " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");

            var answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if ( answer == num1 * num2) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Thats the correct answer!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                ++score; // Gives score
                Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
            } else {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Bummer, try again!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                ++score; // Gives score
                Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
            }
}
```

...

```
Random numbergenerator = new Random ();
int score = 0; // THIS IS THE SCORE

while(true)
{
    int num1 = numbergenerator.Next(1,11);
    int num2 = numbergenerator.Next(1,11);
    TryToGuessMultiplication_GameStep(int num1, int num2);      
}
```

**4) Your code contains bug** If you want to increase score only if aswer is correct you should remove ++score from *else* block.

**5) Do not duplicate the code** As you can see the last 2 statements in both *if* block and *else* block are the same. I suggest to move them out from *if else* operator:

```
public void TryToGuessMultiplication_GameStep(int num1, int num2)
{
            Console.WriteLine("Whats " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");

            var answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if ( answer == num1 * num2) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Thats the correct answer!");
                ++score; // Gives score
            } else {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Bummer, try again!");
            }
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
}
```

It is not all. Now you can see that

```
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Thats the correct answer!");
```

is quite similar (but not the same!!!) to

```
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Bummer, try again!");
```

and we can't improve our code by moving them out of *if else* operator. But there is a trick - we can extract method with help of which we will reduce lines of code:

```
public void PrintUserMessage(ConsoleColor color, string message)
{
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
}

public void TryToGuessMultiplication_GameStep(int num1, int num2)
{
            Console.WriteLine("Whats " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");

            var answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if ( answer == num1 * num2){
                PrintUserMessage( ConsoleColor.Green, "Thats the correct answer!");
                ++score; // Gives score
            }else
                PrintUserMessage( ConsoleColor.Red,"Bummer, try again!");

            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your score is set to 0 after every jump `goto start;`. Put your score declaration above `start:` like below:

```
 int score = 0; // THIS IS THE SCORE
 start:
 ...other instructions
```

Remember, no matter if you are using `goto` or `while`, if variable must store state during a loop, declare and initialize it outside that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting score to 0 every time you `goto start`.

Can you please stop using `goto`? It hurts my eyes, and I believe many other eyes as well. Use `while` instead.

If you use `while` by the way, the problem will disappear as score will not be reset every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use goto it is bad practice, you should use loop instead.

Your code should look like:

```
        Random numbergenerator = new Random();

        int score = 0; // THIS IS THE SCORE

        while (true)
        {
            int num1 = numbergenerator.Next(1, 11);
            int num2 = numbergenerator.Next(1, 11);

            Console.WriteLine("Whats " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");

            var answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (answer == num1 * num2)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Thats the correct answer!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                ++score; // Gives score
                Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Bummer, try again!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("Your score: " + score);
            }
        }
```

Comment: One minor note:  score should not be incremented if they get a wrong answer, probably.

Comment: Edited. About infinite loop, this is what author wanted isn't it? :)

Comment: Personally, I would have refrained from posting a full block of code, because now you'll be criticized for all the other (potential) mistakes in the code that aren't directly related to the question :)

Comment: @sstan from a certain point of view you are correct but I prefer when someone analyzes the problem and give a complete answer to the problem (also if there is something not clear to the OP). For example that Convert.ToInt32 is another big failure point to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers, since you only want to increase the score when the user gets the correct answer, you should remove the `++score;` line from your `else` statement, as the way you currently have it, the score will increase either way, regardless if the answer is correct or not.